# stack snippets en las descripciones extendidas de etiquetas

Tags: característica-nueva, stack-snippets, wiki-de-etiqueta

Me gustaría tener snippets en las descripciones extendidas de las etiquetas porque no siempre recuerdo el CDN de donde se sacaba la librería y cuando piden ayuda he visto que pocos ponen un snippet en sus preguntas o respuestas.

Ventajas:

Para los que editamos las preguntas y para quienes lo leen podrán tener un ejemplo que funciona.

Ejemplo:

[image: snippets no habilitados en descripciones extendidas]

Estoy usando el navegador Firefox.

EnChrome sucede lo mismo y no tiene que ver que no tenga texto, pues nuca se habilita el botón de snippet.

[image: snippets no habilitados en descripciones extendidas]

Comment: ¿Entiendo que ahora el wiki de etiqueta no permite los stack snippets?

Comment: así es estimado

Comment: Estás seguro de eso? Yo acabo de intentar añadir un snippet en una etiqueta y me lo ha permitido. En que etiqueta has probado?

Comment: Ya he añadido la captura, la etiqueta puede ser por ejemplo [datetimepicker]

Comment: tu idea es que aparte de la docimentacion traerte tambien los ejemplos funcionales... no se no tiene  sentido...

Comment: y me parece que esto tendrias que pedirlo en meta.se